# How did Sato get the file?

Tags: dan-brown, the-lost-symbol

In Dan Brown's [The Lost Symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lost_Symbol), Sato convinces Bellamy and Langdon to help her by  showing them a footage of weird masonic rites, attended by key US personalities. The video was shot by the antagonist of the book (Mal'akh) and revealing it publicly would trigger a national crisis.

How did she get that file?